# How can change style element on page

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-4

If I have below style and I want to change it on click Event

```
           .amet:before,
            .amet:after,
            .amet .side > div,
            .amet .corner > div {
                position: absolute;
                background-image: url();
            }
```

Some one plz suggest me. What shuld I do.

Comment: As the question is not so clear, I'll only show you how you can find a solution. As far as I can see you've a amet class, when a click event occures your can add a new class for example amet.clickedxxx and add this class to your css as .amet.clickedxxx and change the style, or remove the amit class and just add a new class as amit1, and add this one into the css as .amit1.before etc. hope this will show you the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

step 1: put your style into a div ()
step 2: send ajax request on click event.
step 3: create required style on Controller and send it back on page.
step 4: empty your div and replace with html return by ajax success( $('.style-change').empty(); $('.style-change').html(html);  )

Answer (score 2):

```
$(obj).click(function(){
    $(".amet").css({
          your style here
    });
    $(".amet .corner > div").css({
         backgroundImage: url,
         position: "static"
    });
});
```